# Make an image disappear onClick in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am taking a cool JavaScript course called "Javascript Tutorial". The video instruction showed something that is not happening for me. What is supposed to happen is to click on an image with an HTML tag of `logo` to make it disappear, then click a button that says "Get Logo" to bring it back.

Here is an excerpt of the `jstut.html` file I have been building throughout the course:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lan="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="jstut.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    body {font-size: 1.6em;}
    .hidden {display:none;}
    .show {display:inLine !important;}
    button {
     border: 2px solid black; background: #ESE4E2;
     font-size: .5em; font-weight: bold; color: black;
     padding: .8em 2em;
     margin-top: .4em;
    }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <img src="ntt-logo.png" id="logo">
  <button id="logoButton" type='text'>Get Logo</button>
 <script>
  document.getElementById('logoButton').onClick = function(event){
   document.getElementById('logo').className = "show";
  }

  document.getElementById('logo').onClick = function(event){
     document.getElementById('logo').className = "hidden";
  }    
 </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I compared my syntax to that of the course and it is an exact match. Please help me make the image disappear when I click on it.

I am using Firefox. I tried this with IE and Chrome, but it behaves the same way.

Comment: javascript is case sensitive, it's `onclick` not `onClick`

Comment: @host_255 what is in the jstut.js file you're  referencing in the head of the html file?

Comment: I'm voting to close.  The only (functional) problem with this code is the `onclick` syntax/case sensitivity issue.

Comment: That is exactly what it was. The instructor was using .onClick on Mac and the functions worked on Chrome. I don't quite get that. But, .onclick works fine. @Makyen

Comment: @TomGillard the jstut.js file contains one line that was used by the jstut.html file earlier in the video, which I commented out, and has nothing to do with this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code matches the tutorial you mentioned *almost* exactly. You have differed in that you have been calling `.onClick` where you should have been setting [`.onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers):

```
document.getElementById('logoButton').onclick = function(event) {
   document.getElementById('logo').className = "show";
}

document.getElementById('logo').onclick = function(event) {
    document.getElementById('logo').className = "hidden";
}
```

Note that [properties are case sensitive in JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_syntax.asp).

```js
  document.getElementById('logoButton').onclick = function(event) {
    document.getElementById('logo').className = "show";
  }

  document.getElementById('logo').onclick = function(event) {
    document.getElementById('logo').className = "hidden";
  }
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 1.6em;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: inLine !important;
}
button {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: #ESE4E2;
  font-size: .5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  padding: .8em 2em;
  margin-top: .4em;
}
```

```html
<img src="//placehold.it/200x200" id="logo">
<button id="logoButton" type='text'>Get Logo</button>
```

Comment: [This is the course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fju9ii8YsGs). About 1 hour 2 min 29 sec in, you will see that the instructor uses `onClick` and it works on Chrome on his Mac. I am using Windows 7 Home Premium, Firefox, Chrome, IE, etc. I don't know if that makes any difference or why `onClick` works for him but not me. I feel that is something I should know. Do you have any idea? @Robin James Kerrison

Comment: @host_255 That `onClick` must have been an unfortunate typo. At 1:02:49, you'll see that it does say `onclick` following a strange jump cut. This is likely a [One I Prepared Earlier](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OneIPreparedEarlier) moment.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to toggle between showing and hiding an element is using jQuery toggleClass function.

```js
$('#logoButton').click(function() {
  $('#logo').toggleClass('hidden')
});
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 1.6em;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
#logoButton {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
button {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: #ESE4E2;
  font-size: .5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  padding: .8em 2em;
  margin-top: .4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lan="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="jstut.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <button id="logoButton" type='text'>Get Logo</button>
  <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/23695_pets_vertical_store_dogs_small_tile_8._CB312176604_.jpg" id="logo">


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I agree that JQuery is better. The course does not teach JQuery. I have another 6 hour video tutorial I am going to take, then I think JQuery is my next subject to learn. Thank you!

Comment: Providing a jQuery solution for a Question that is specifically tagged JavaScript and *not* jQuery when neither the question text nor the OP's comments contain any hint that th OP is using jQuery is counterproductive.